# HDMI output for 1080p

Tags: hdmi, config.txt

Need the right configuration to set the standards for the config.txt file to set an PAL LCD 1080p.

I have tried `hdmi_group` set to `0`, to use the preferred group.
That tweak gave me sharp text although the LCD output in unscaled mode gave me a small output box screen in the centre of the LCD.

I also set these parameters that gave the same output, small centre box in unscaled LCD mode. In auto-zoom LCD mode the image did fill out the screen, although I get the sense that it leaves out to much when viewing a web page for example, just as it does in unscaled LCD mode.

```
sdtv_mode=2
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=82
```

**The correct configuration for a 16:9 PAL 1920x1080- 60Hz are:**

```
sdtv_mode=2
sdtv_aspect=3
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16
disable_overscan=1
```

Comment: It is my understanding the default behavior is to auto negotiate the highest resolution common to both tv and Pi.  Any reason 1080p is not chosen then?

Comment: Some displays apply overscan, even on digital inputs. Is it a TV display by any chance? Try changing overscan_left, overscan_right, overscan_top, and overscan_bottom

Comment: `disable_overscan=1` fixes the overscan issue on the TV. 1080p is chosen with `hdmi_mode=16`

Answer (score 2):

I changed the `config.txt` located at `/boot`, including the following statement:

```
hdmi_mode=16
```

I also had to change `overscan_left` and `overscan_right`.

I used the method of trial and error to find the right numbers for the overscan.

Comment: Looking at your answers compared to the question and the comments in this question, you seem to think this website is a forum.  *It isn't*.  This is a Q&A site.  Please see the [help center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) for more information.

Comment: actually, in my case, this was the issue.  the resolution was fine, I just had to adjust the overscan settings

Comment: How do you get the `hdmi_mode=16`? Is there a standard reference table for it? My display is 1024 x 600. What `hdmi_mode` will it be?

Comment: @Blaise https://elinux.org/RPi_Configuration